# Titles are not shown in exported excel file from primefaces datatable

Tags: excel, primefaces, datatable, export

I got primefaces datatable with filters used. every works fine. but when i export the datatable to excel file the titles are not shown.

Here I use external remoteCommand to handle the event on the server side.

**here is the xhtml code:**

```
<h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="#{dictionary['export_to_excel']}" icon="ui-icon-calculator" ajax="false">
                                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target=":gwsReportAllPartForm:gwsReportAllPartListDataTable" fileName="analytics"/>  
                            </p:commandButton>  
                        </h:form>

<h:form id="gwsReportAllPartForm">
                            <p:remoteCommand name="updateFilters" update=":gwsReportAllPartForm:gwsReportAllPartListDataTable"></p:remoteCommand>
                        <p:dataTable  id="gwsReportAllPartListDataTable" 
                                      value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.gwsReportPartTwoList}" 
                                      var="report" 
                                      paginator="true" 
                                      rows="100"
                                      paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks} {CurrentPageReport}" 
                                      currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} #{dictionary['out_of']} {totalPages}" 
                                      emptyMessage="#{dictionary['nothing_is_here']}" 
                                      scrollable="true"
                                      scrollWidth="1050"
                                      scrollHeight="500">

                            <p:ajax event="filter"  listener="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.onFilterDataTable}" oncomplete="updateFilters()"/>

                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['reporting_period']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 90px;position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.year}, #{report.gwsReportPartOne.quarter}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['subsoil_user_contract_register_number']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 90px;position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.contractNumber}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:80px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;" filterValue="">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.contractNumber}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['gws_type']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 40px;position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.gwsType.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:30px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.gwsType.code}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column id="tender_code" headerText="#{dictionary['gws_code_by_skp']}" width="100" style="position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" styleClass="columnCustomClass" filterBy="#{report.skp.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:90px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.skp.code}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['item_name_and_short_description_of_purchased_gws']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 150px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.description}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:140px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.description}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['purchase_way']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 50px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.tenderType.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:40px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.tenderType.code}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['agreement_number']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementNumber}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementNumber}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['tender_result_date']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.resultDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.resultDate}" >
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['agreement_conclusion_date']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStartDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStartDate}" >
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['agreement_deadline_date']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementEndDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementEndDate}" >
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                                </h:outputText>                                   
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['agreement_status']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 50px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStatus.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:40px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStatus.code}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['total_sum_of_agreement_without_vat']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementSum}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementSum)}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['planned_sum_in_gpz_without_vat']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.plannedSum}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsReportPartOne.plannedSum)}" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['actually_paid_sum_for_report_period_of_agreement_without_vat']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.actuallyPaidSum}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsReportPartOne.actuallyPaidSum)}" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['tender_volume_without_vat_in_price']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 100px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px; background-color: #{two.gwsSumWithoutVatColor}" filterBy="#{report.gwsSumWithoutVat}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:90px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsSumWithoutVat)}">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['supplier_bin_iin']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierBinOrIin}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierBinOrIin}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['supplier_gws_name']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 150px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierName}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:140px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierName}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['supplier_gws_country']}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 60px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierCountry.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:50px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierCountry.code}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['local_content_piece']}, %" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.kazcontent}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{report.kazcontent}" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                                <ui:remove><h:outputText value="#{report.kazcontentInService}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                    </h:outputText></ui:remove>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{dictionary['procurement_sum_of_local_content_of_tru']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.procurementSumOfLocalContentOfGws}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.procurementSumOfLocalContentOfGws)}" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:columnGroup type="footer">  
                                <p:row>  
                                    <p:column footerText="#{dictionary['totals']}: " style="text-align:right"/>  
                                    <p:column footerText="" />  
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalAgreementSum}" />
                                    <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalPlannedSum}" />
                                    <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalActualPaid}" />
                                    <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalGwsSum}" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="" />
                                    <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.averageKazContent} %" />
                                    <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalGwsLocalContent}" />
                                </p:row>  
                            </p:columnGroup>  
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use `f:facet` instead `headerText` attribute in `p:column`, for example:

```
<p:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText id="header1" value="#{dictionary['some_key']}" />
   </f:facet>
   ...
</p:column>
```

Comment: Great! I have absolutely forgot about f:facet. not it works fine! thank you!